# Are questions about cartoons on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We've had a couple of questions recently about identifying plants from cartoons:

- https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9890/what-is-this-carnivorous-plant
- [What is the flower just above the groom's left breast?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/11047/what-is-the-flower-just-above-the-grooms-left-breast)

Are these questions on-topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, you can't make a scientific assessment of this type of picture, as the artists are usually not botanists, and do not draw plants consistent in all characteristics to the real things. I would prefer that these not be on topic. If they can't find a photograph, they can't get a great answer. I agree with @kevinsky that they are rather amusing.

"Doubt the plant actually has teeth with blood dripping from them. Giving the author the benefit of the doubt, but the "sketch" is not helpful." - Robert Cartaino, in an edit summary.

Answer (score 6):

They are amusing if nothing else.  If we get lots of them I would think putting them outside of scope is reasonable but one or two now and then is not an issue when we are trying to build the user base.

(That is if you agree that a user who got an answer here once is more likely to return in the future with another, hopefully on topic, question.)